# Various name errors produced by one cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, portfolio

In this code I have a cell that has produced three different name errors. First was `NameError: name 'np' is not defined`, the second was `NameError: name 'weight_portfolio' is not defined`. I got rid of these two.

The third name error is `NameError: name 'variance_matrix' is not defined`. As you can see they sure are all defined. What is the matter? I can get rid of this as well by defining `variance_matrix` again, but then name error just moves to another variable in the cell.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as sco

stocks = ['corp1','corp2','corp3','corp4']
pf_data = pd.DataFrame()   
for stock in stocks:
    pf_data[stock] = web.DataReader(stock, data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2008-1-1')['Adj Close']
num_stocks = len(stocks)
pf_data

portfolio = pf_data

returns_portfolio = portfolio.pct_change()

weight_portfolio = [0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1]
portfolio_return = returns_portfolio.dot(weight_portfolio)

variance_matrix = returns_portfolio.cov()*252
```

Then comes the cell that contains the error. I know very little about the usage of decorators, but I guess the @ sign has something to do with the error.

```
#computing porfolio variance
portfolio_variance = np.transpose(weight_portfolio)@variance_matrix@weight_portfolio

#computing portfolio volatility i.e. risk
portfolio_volatility = np.sqrt(portfolio_variance)

print("Portfolio variance is", portfolio_variance)
print("Portfolio volatility is", portfolio_volatility)
```

Comment: The talk of `cell` suggests you are using a Jupyter notebook.  If the 2nd cell depends on variables created in the first, make sure you run the first after all edits.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import numpy in this way: from numpy import * or import numpy without an alias (np in your case).

Comment: That won't allow him to write `np.sqrt()`.

Comment: Of course, you can be able to write only sqrt with the first option or numpy.sqrt with the second option that I write.

Comment: Why doesn't `import numpy as np` work for him? That's how everyone normally uses it.

Comment: I don't know why you have this problem but try to check here https://pythontect.com/import-numpy-as-np-tutorial/

Comment: I edited the question to make it more precise. I got rid of that numpy issue, and I'm struggling with that undefined ```variance_matrix```

Comment: I think that var_matrix is the same thing of variance matrix, maybe a misclick from the author. But I don't know why you have this problem, it's correct

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I got it working by running everything from the start. I don't understand what was wrong in the code as I hadn't changed it

Comment: most cases: import numpy as np